# Trying to solve a Pin algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, brute-force

I'm trying to brute force a pin code problem, and i'm running into to some problems.

http://alvaray.org/brute-forcing-pincode-keypads-using-combinatorial-mathematics/

The link I included discusses the exact problem i'm trying to solve. Now it does include a link on the page to a formula, but I'm trying to create my own without using theirs.  My goal is to shorten it from 40,000 combinations period.  If i can get to 10,003 that would be cool, but, the ultimate goal is to just shorten it from the max. 
My code looks like this:

```
import random

codes = []
shortest_combination = []
one_big_string = []
garbage_string = []
for a in range(0,10):
    for b in range(0,10):
        for c in range(0,10):
            for d in range(0,10):
                codes.append(str(a) + str(b) + str(c) + str(d))


random.shuffle(codes)
shortest_combination.append(codes[0:1])
codes.remove(codes[0:1])
"".join(shortest_combination)

for code in codes:
    for short in shortest_combination:
         codes.index(short[short + 1:len(short)])
         find = shortest_combination.append(codes[short: len(short) + 1])
         codes.remove(find)
         "".join(shortest_combination)

 print shortest_combination
```

Unfortunately i'm getting this error:
    ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
I'm not sure i'm I using remove wrong? Please help, plus any feedback regarding if i'm approaching the problem right also be helpful.  Thank You

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `codes[0:1]` is a list with one element. What you want is `codes[0]`:

```
In [1]: codes = ["a", "b", "c"]

In [2]: codes[0:1]
Out[2]: ['a']

In [3]: codes[0]
Out[3]: 'a'
```

Comment: wow hahaha i'm idiot, thank you that worked. now the rest of code is different dilemma altogether lol. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error was already revealed by Jack Maney, so I'm going to answer your other problem:

> My goal is to shorten it from 40,000 combinations period. If i can get to 10,003 that would be cool

What you want is the [De Brujin sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence). The wikipedia page is also linked in the articled you've read, and it contains code for finding such a sequence. It involves building a [De Brujin graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph) and finding an [Eulerian cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path) in it.

Unfortunately, it will be very hard to come up with an (efficient) algorithm to reduce the length without using this. If you did manage it, I'm pretty sure your work would be publishable. I suggest you try to understand the logic behind how De Brujin graphs are constructed and how an Eulerian cycle is found.

Comment: No yeah i saw that,  but like I said I'm trying to create my own, and my friend was able to do, as well as my boss with a different formula.  He got it shortened by only a few, which is my goal as well, and my boss got to 10,004 by his own deduction.  But thanks for the advice though